# Webdev serve command

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-web

I tried to run my flutter web project on browser using webdev serve command but it showed me the following error:

> ~/Desktop/web_project/hello_world$ webdev serve
>   webdev could not run for this project.
>   Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/home/mehdi1514/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/protobuf-0.13.11".

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate. It is already answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56657021/361832

and also here:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32313