# Why my flutter web app does not run upon running webdev serve

Tags: flutter-web

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJfp9.png)I've build my flutter web app and when I run webdev serve
I've got this error message

> webdev could not run for this project.
>   Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in
>    "C:\Users\Karrar\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\protobuf-0.13.12".

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Show your directory structure and from which directory are you running `webdev serve`?

Comment: `flutter packages pub global run webdev serve`
Try this command it worked for me.

Comment: @TirthPatel I've attached a photo for my project to see the structure of directories , I'm running webdev serve once I'm inside the project

Comment: didn't worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It is answered here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32313

You have two options:

1. use longer command instead: `flutter packages pub global run webdev serve`

or

2. add `protobuf: ^0.13.11` to your project dependencies and run `pub get`, this will fetch missing dependency for `webdev`, then you can remove `protobuf` from your project

Comment: I've got this message after running pub get    Resolving dependencies...
Cannot find a Git executable.
Please ensure Git is correctly installed.

Comment: @Karrar it is a different issue please post separate question